# Fazer com que um TextBox leia um número binário. C#

Tags: c#

Olá,

Estou fazendo um programa que simula uma ULA(unidade lógica programável), e preciso que os meus textbox leiam o valor escrito em binário.

**Por exemplo: No TextBox1 o usuário escreveria 1010(número 10 em decimal).**

Eu preciso que esse valor seja entendido como binário.
Já consigo converter de binário para decimal e vice-versa, mas o que eu preciso mesmo, é que o textBox já leia o número que vai ser colocado dentro dele pelo usuário como binário.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Vc quer que o textbox só aceite 0 e 1, é isso?

Comment: É Windows Forms, Asp.NET WebForms, Asp.NET MVC, Silverlight, WPF? Fica difícil ajudar sem saber qual tecnologia está usando especificamente....

Comment: É windows form application. Eu quero que o valor que seja lido seja binário.

Se eu escrever 1100 no textbox, ele tem que entender como 12. 
Não sei se ta dando pra entender bem o que eu quero! hahaha

Comment: Ponha o código atual do textbox, fica mais fácil de ajudarem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O texto que for colocado em sua TextBox pode ser convertido desta forma:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text, 2);
```

Esta classe [Convert](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_) serve para conversão em várias bases numéricas. No link tem outro exemplos.

Comment: Vlw cara, não sabia dessa propriedade do convert. Ajudou bastante.